# How can I convert/use/fix my existing JSX code to work with Bootstraps display properties?

Tags: reactjs

I am stuck with my project, so I need some help. A few months ago I built a single-page webpage using HTML, CSS, and JAVASCRIPT.

Now I am working on the same webpage, but I am building it in REACT JS.

Code example from the previous version

```
<sectio id="topbar" class="d-none d-lg-block">
      <div class="dontainer d-flex">
        <div class="contact-info mr-auto">
          <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
            <a href="mailto:"example@example.com">example@example.com &nbsp;</a>
            <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
              <a href="tel: example">example&nbsp; &nbsp;</a>
              <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
                <a href="https:example">lorem lorem</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </sectio>
```

The same code but in JSX with className

```
const TopBar = () => {
  return (
    <section id="topbar" className="d-none d-lg-block">
      <div className="dontainer d-flex">
        <div className="contact-info mr-auto">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEnvelope} style={{ color: "#efa036" }} />
          <i className="fas fa-envelope"></i>
          <a href="mailto:example@example.com">example@example.com &nbsp;</a>
          <i className="fas fa-phone"></i>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPhone} style={{ color: "#efa036" }} />
          <a href="tel:example example &nbsp;</a>
          <i className="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLocationDot} style={{ color: "#efa036" }} />
          <a href="example">
            example
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
```

The problem is that I can't use the Bootstrap classes (those classes are for display properties) from the previous version (HTML, CSS, JS) in the new React JS version. The display property of Boostrap simply doesn't work.

**The question is how can I convert/use/fix my existing JSX code to work with Bootstraps display properties just like the previous version does?**

P.S.

I have installed Boostrap ( "bootstrap": "^5.3.1",) in NPM in my VS CODE terminal.

Comment: In what way does the code not work as expected?  In the resulting markup in the browser, are the expected `class` values present?  If not, what is that resulting markup?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you import the   import bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css in app.jsx  second, check the spell of classes as well like container  flex not   otherwise its same as version 4 of bootstrap

Comment: Thank you for your help! The problem was that I haven't importws bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css in my App.js file.